Support two task tracker links in Gitea
Recently our company had changed task tracker from Youtrack to Openproject. Gitea history contains large number of commits with links to Youtrack tasks via codes like "TSK-1234 <commit message>", where "TSK-1234" is a clickable link.

Also Gitea doesn't support links at two trackers. Our admin decide to support only new (openproject) tasks and links, and all the huge amount of old links became invalid.
It seems to me that Gitea can support two trackers via some simple intermediate http-server, that will just devide links from Gitea and redirect to Youtrack/Openproject.
I want to convince our admin to implement this solution so that we don't lose the ability to navigate through the commit history normally. Therefore I need to understand the basic steps of such a solution. Am I correct in assuming that the a simple http-server can make that redirects (if we if we make the links differ by one character, e.g. TSK- and TSK_)? What a type of operation it shall do? How to bind the server to our corporate subdomain and run it (in general terms?). Are that tasks really difficult?
